# Using NUnit, how to I assert that a web element is not visible?

Tags: nunit, selenium-webdriver

I'm using NUnit to run Selenium tests written in C#. I can easilt assert that elements exist after a test has run but how do I use assertions to verify that an element does not exist?
For example, one tests deletes a user and I need to verify that the user's name does not appear on the list afterwards.
Any suggestions are very welcome.
John

Comment: Show the code you are using now.

Comment: Apologies for the delay - thanks for your suggestion. The code I'm currently using seems to work fine but the Assert take about 20-30 seconds to complete for some reason. I'm using Firefox. 'Assert.IsFalse(Global.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='" + tagGroupName + "']")).Displayed);'

Comment: That's entirely different problem than what you put here. Please create a new one.

Comment: @Arran - after testing this a bit more, it does seem that NNit is the problem and not Selenium. Thanks.

Comment: How did you verify that?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the assertTrue(bool b) method work for this purpose?

For example assertTrue(!list.Contains(item))